# PDT Eclipse Annoying Bug with Namespaces and external project

Tags: php, eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse PHP (PDT) 64bit; Java 64bit. It loads fine.

Then I imported Handlebars; handlebars.js, two projects from Github. And my own; separate project.

Because it's a new installation since a while, it also came with PHP7 for the first time for me.

It started showing these annoying errors, and I can't get rid of them. Googled about it, to no avail. I could ask on stackoverflow, but Im sure they will complain about 'software specific issue' if I did.

Can someone help me out; is this a project setting that I overlooked (Ie. do I need to add a 'linked project' of Handlebars, etc.). It seems like an easy fix to me, I just dont see the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: The solution to my problem]

You need to add those projects as 'included libraries' first.

1. In the *Project Explorer*, Right click on your project, click *Properties*.
2. Expand and select *PHP > Source Paths > Include Path*
3. Select the *Projects* tab.
4. Click *Add*.
5. Select the project(s) whose code contains the correct references/namespaces/classes etc.
6. Click *OK*.
7. Click Apply and Close.

That should do it, and it worked for me. Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: i have this already but some of my files still keep complaining